# invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘int’)

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

im sorry for repeating the question, but i cant get my head around (what i think my problem is) pointers. Can someone please shed some light onto this for me? Ive trawled through heaps of stackoverflow questions, c tutoriols and its mostly confusing as each solution seems to contradict another - if i see my code being fixed im sure that will help me to fully understand

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2 getinput()
3 {
4 int *employeeSalary[5];
5 int i;
6         for(i=0;i<5;i++)
7         {
8                 printf("Enter details of employee no. %d :",i+1);
9                 scanf("%d",&employeeSalary[i]);
10         }
11 return(*employeeSalary);
12 }
13 
14 int payrise(int *employeeSalary[])
15 {
16 int *newSalary = ((employeeSalary*0.20)*100);
17 return(*newSalary);
18 }
19 
20 int highestSalary(int *newSalary)
21 {
22 int i = 0;
23 int biggestSalary;
24 int element;
25         if(newSalary[i] >= newSalary[i])
26         {
27                 biggestSalary = newSalary[i];
28                 element = i;
29         }
30 return(biggestSalary, element);
31 }
32 
33 void display(int *employeeSalary, int *newSalary, int biggestSalary, int element)
34 {
35 printf("The old salary was %d and the new one is %d ", employeeSalary, newSalary);
36 printf("The biggest salaray is %d in element %d", biggestSalary, element);
37 }
38 
39 
40 int main()
41 {
42 int initialSalary = getinput();
43 int payIncrease = payrise(initialSalary);
44 int largestSalary = highestSalary(payIncrease);
45 display(initialSalary, payIncrease, largestSalary);
46 return(0);
47 }
```

These are the errors im getting

```
11: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘int’)
16: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int ***’ and ‘double’) 
17: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘int’)
45: error: too few arguments to function ‘display’
```

Comment: This is just a pile of pointer errors. For instance: LINE 4 `employeeSalary` is an array of pointers to `int`. The return type of `getinput()` should therefore be `int*`

Comment: As your compiler reported you can not do `16 int *newSalary = ((employeeSalary*0.20)*100);`

Comment: `int initialSalary = getinput();` again `getinput()` returns a pointer. So `initialSalary` should be an `int*` . However, I fail to see, why you are using pointers for every single variable...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_OF_EMPLOYEE 5

int *getinput(void){
    int i, *employeeSalary = calloc(NUM_OF_EMPLOYEE, sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<NUM_OF_EMPLOYEE;++i){
        printf("Enter details of employee no. %d :", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &employeeSalary[i]);
    }
    return employeeSalary;
}

int *payrise(int employeeSalary[]){
    int i, *newSalary = malloc(NUM_OF_EMPLOYEE * sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<NUM_OF_EMPLOYEE;++i){
        newSalary[i] = employeeSalary[i]*1.20;//*0.20*100 = *20.0
    }
    return newSalary;
}

int highestSalary(int *newSalary){
    int biggestSalary = newSalary[0];
    int element = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for(i=1;i<NUM_OF_EMPLOYEE;++i){
        if(newSalary[i] > biggestSalary){
            biggestSalary = newSalary[i];
            element = i;
        }
    }
    return element;
}

void display(int *employeeSalary, int *newSalary, int biggestSalary, int element){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<NUM_OF_EMPLOYEE;++i){
        printf("The old salary was %d and the new one is %d\n", employeeSalary[i], newSalary[i]);
    }
    printf("The biggest salaray is %d in element %d\n", biggestSalary, element);
}

int main(){
    int *initialSalary = getinput();
    int *payIncrease = payrise(initialSalary);
    int index = highestSalary(payIncrease);
    int largestSalary = payIncrease[index];
    display(initialSalary, payIncrease, largestSalary, index);

    free(initialSalary);free(payIncrease);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 Please don't post code dumps without explanation. This is answer is useless to anyone but the OP, and even for that person, it doesn't help them understand, it just lets them continue to write code by copy-and-paste.

Comment: @siride very true but definitely helps me out

Comment: @dazza2608: this site isn't a "please fix my code for me" site, so that ain't gonna fly. It doesn't actually help you either. Do you truly understand what was wrong? If not, then you have not really been helped.

Comment: @siride i know its not a "please fix my code for me" site, BLUEPIXY did fix my code though and from that i can see what i needed to do - I can now see where my pointers where worng and that i needed to dynamically allocate memory and sorted my issue with getting the percentage so that i can now use all of this for the future. I completely understand that for the community it isnt a good answer, but for me it was exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

On line 2 you have what looks like a function declaration without a return type, try adding one.

Comment: That is an error but its only one of many.  You might be better posting a comment rather than an answer if you're not going to tackle some of the other issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly typing issues
what @lijat said is correct. On line 16 you have an assignment without cast of different types.
`((employeeSalary*0.20)*100)` is of type int *[] which is actually int** so you either need to have the left side int** or de-reference the right side one more time (add * at the beginning of the expression.
Line 17 needs a space after return.
line 45 you're missing a parameter, the function display receives 4 and you gave it only 3.

Comment: Great Thank you @inneedofhelp, im just stuck with 'line 45 you're missing a parameter, the function display receives 4 and you gave it only 3'
 is there a way i can return 2 things from one function and pass them through to another or do i have to splt them up?

Comment: You can send an out parameter as a pointer/reference and return the output in that parameter.

Answer (score -1):

You are using pointers all wrong. Please read about pointers before attempting to use them. I will try to point out your mistakes:

```
2 getinput() //<-- no return type? should return int*
3 {
4 int *employeeSalary[5];
5 int i;
6         for(i=0;i<5;i++)
7         {
8                 printf("Enter details of employee no. %d :",i+1);
9                 scanf("%d",&employeeSalary[i]);
10         }
11 return(*employeeSalary); //<-- I guess you wanted to return the whole array. This only returns the 1st element
12 }




14 int payrise(int *employeeSalary[])//<-- must return an integer
15 {
16 int *newSalary = ((employeeSalary*0.20)*100); <-- employeeSalary is an array of int pointers, therefore this is invalid
17 return(*newSalary); 
18 }




20 int highestSalary(int *newSalary) //<-- must return an integer like 5 or 3 ...
21 {
22 int i = 0;
23 int biggestSalary;
24 int element;
25         if(newSalary[i] >= newSalary[i]) //<-- isn't this always true, i.e. always equal?
26         {
27                 biggestSalary = newSalary[i];
28                 element = i;
29         }
30 return(biggestSalary, element); //<-- no comment! I don't know what you are trying to do here
31 }


void display(int *employeeSalary, int *newSalary, int biggestSalary, int element)
34 {
35 printf("The old salary was %d and the new one is %d ", employeeSalary, newSalary);//employeeSlary and newSalary are pointersn you need to dereference them.
36 printf("The biggest salaray is %d in element %d", biggestSalary, element);
37 }
```

I highly suggest you look up a c tutorial online and follow it. It seems you are unable to distinguish between variable types and pointers.